# Query string not recognized

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, query-string, wcf-ria-services

I have to following problem:
When I go to my site:

```
http://localhost:9684/MainPage.aspx?UserID=VABRAEIAUgBBAEUARQBBAFAAUQBBAD0A
```

It has to check if there is a query string (UserID) and if there is a query string it has to save it in the variable `sIngelogdID` I'm useing the following code for this:

```
string sIngelogdID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["UserID"];
```

However when I look at it in debug mode it says that there are 0 query strings, so it doesn't see `UserID` as a query string.
This is written in a WCF-RIA-service.
Does anybody have an idea how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The `UserID` comes from a different Silverlight 4 application. At this application the user logs in after that the login details (the Id of the user that logged in) has to be passed to another Silverlight 4 application. If there is another way (better) way to achieve this, also please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [InitParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838255(v=vs.95).aspx) instead for sending values.

Firstly capture the querystring from the aspx page which hosted your silverlight application,
In MainPage.aspx.cs

```
public string GetUserId()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["UserId"];
}
```

Now under MainPage.aspx you need to insert code as below under body=> form=> find param and add

```
<param name="InitParams" value="param1=<%= GetUserId() %>" />
```

Now capture the param1 in the App.xaml.cs Application_Startup method as

```
        if (e.InitParams.ContainsKey("param1"))
        {
            userId = e.InitParams["param1"].ToString();
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you please explain me a bit more about InitParms and how would I use it? Also the UserID has to come from a different Silverlight application on which the user logins and then the login details should go to the other system.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit. Are you not getting the querystring in the aspx page that hosted your silverlight application or in your silverlight XAML page.If you are trying to get the querystring value in the aspx page then the method done by you should work o/w let me know I will provide you the way to pass value from aspx page to the Xaml page.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, (my project is called 'Meldingenportaal') I'm afraid my MainPage.aspx (which in my case is 'Meldingenportaal.aspx' (the project name, is this correct?), it is the one in Meldingenportaal.Web. However I do have a MainPage but that is in the normal solution (Meldingenportaal) and that MainPage is the MainPage.xaml. However in the Meldingenportaal.web the Meldingenportaal.aspx file (which is the startup file) does NOT contain a Meldingenportaal.aspx.cs file, is this correct? Because I don't seem to be able to find MainPage.aspx.cs

Comment: I tried adding Meldingenportaal.aspx.cs manually and adding the code in there, next I put on the top of Meldingportaal.aspx after AutoEventWireup the CodeBeheind="Meldingenportaal.aspx.cs" however it still says it doesn't recognize GetUserId() in the Meldingenportaal.aspx

Comment: Just tried <param name="InitParams" value="param1=<%= GetUserId() %>" /> replacing with <param name="InitParams" value="param1=<%= HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["UserId"] %>" /> and this works fine! +1 for all your help! A huge amount of thanks to you!